# File opening in java as a android static java module

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a file using bufferreader in java code.

But when it trues to open it it is throwing below error.
System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/ (Permission denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both permission in Android Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and if you are allowing both permission in android application after that you can use this code:

```
File file = new File("file path"); 

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

  String st; 
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(st); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your **manifest file**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Use this like in java

```
if( new File("file path here").exists())
   {//use your code here}
```